# sqlite select query faster in shell than C/C++

Tags: c++, shell, sqlite

I have a simple database/table with about 1M records. No indexing, all clean. The sqlite3 shell executes the following query in 4.4 sec:

select * from table order by emission asc limit 30;

The exact same statement in windows10 / VS2017 / sqlite 3.20.0 takes 14s:

```
        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
        sqlite3_step(stmt);
```

I went through all the pragmas. No luck. Any idea where the performance difference can come from?

**Found something:**

As usual, the issue is not where we look. The optimizations through pragmas were marginal for the given query. However, I tested the code in debug and release mode, the difference is huge:

No optimization, debug: 13.7 sec
Whole optimization / size, release: 2.5 sec !

There is an option somewhere that has a significant influence on speed. It would be nice to know which one and apply it in debug mode.

**Found it:**

I use the amalgamation. Applying the proper compilation / linking options is key.

Default / current options: 14.4 sec
Changed debug info format from /ZI to Zi: 9.7 sec
Changed Basic Runtime Checks from /RTC1 to default: 5.4 sec
Changed optimization /Od (disabled) to /O1 (size): 3.0 sec

That was a lot of trials, errors and discoveries. I hope it helps someone!

Comment: Is this the very first statement after opening the database? The first `prepare` call reads and parses the database schema. Though it would have to be an enormous schema for this to take 10 seconds.

Comment: It's also likely that some data is cached; time the *second* execution of the query. (And just to rule out other differences: same version? Is the [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output the same?)

Comment: The select is the first statement in the shell. EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN gives the same two lines (shell and C/C++): SCAN TABLE and USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY.